# Application blocked by security settings

Tags: java, security, applet

I'm trying to play Java applets from [bodo.com](http://www.bodo.com/Applets/Blocks/index.html)
but whenever I click on one of the games, I get a pop-up that says:

```
Application blocked by security settings
Name: "game"
Location: http://www.bodo.com
Your security settings have blocked an application from running with an 
    out-of-date or expired version of java.
```

I don't understand this because I have the latest version of Java installed.

Comment: read [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

Comment: @ImmerAllein  You should flesh that out (expand it) and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem myself. To solve this I went to the *Windows Control Panel* -> *Programs* -> *Java*. There you go to *Security* and press *Edit Site List...*, click *Add* and there you type in the location (http://www.bodo.com) and press *OK*.

If you still have problem you can try changing the Security Level to Medium and this you also manage under the *Security* tab in Java Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the exception site list helped when the applet is not signed or certified.

For out of date error, I need to change the security level to medium.
And make sure you close all the browser windows and start fresh after you made the changes.

The instruction here shows how to change security level: [JCP security help on Java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)